What do i need to simulate my robot's movement on computer?
I'm planning on using ROS2 with Gazebo to simulate and visualize my robot's movements (controlled with a raspberrypi and an ESP32)
first, would i need to install ubuntu on my computer (windows 10) or just for my raspberry.
second, for installin packages and all the tools i need, do i need to install them on my computer, raspberry or both.
i'm just lost on what device i should be downloading on.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

By simulating, I would assume you don't have any hardware, and you are trying to test you robot's algorithm within a virtual environment. By visualizing (as you would with RViz, and not Gazebo), I assume you would be using hardware that sends data to your PC and represents your robot in a virtually reconstructed environment of your real-life surroundings.
If it's the former, you just need ROS and Gazebo on your PC to do all your tests, simulations and evaluations. If it's the latter, it depends on how your system is implemented. Naturally, its best to have ROS installed on PC and raspberry pi, but only your PC would require RViz (Or Gazebo if you have something else in mind that I am not aware about).
As for the tools and packages you need, usually, you will require to download packages related to sensing (accelerometer, IMUs, LiDARs, Ultrasound, Cameras) and actuation (your choice of motor control packages) on your Raspberry Pi. This data can be transmitted to your PC for processing using tech stacks like Navigation2 to create visualization of your robot in virtual space with the aid sensor fusion packages like robot_localization. Hence these pacakges can be installed on PC and not necessary on Raspberry Pi.
Note:
You could also consider leaving robot_localization package on the Raspberry Pi and send the processed data to PC for further analysis. It's all up to you on how you wish to split the processing power and manage the data transmission as you would have a limit on your bandwidth.
A simple to rule to keep in mind is is this package used by this device? If yes, download, if not, skip.

i'm sorry for the misunderstanding, i meant visualize, the robot will be controlled with a ESP32 and raspberry pi.
the robot will be a ground vehicle, and the goal is to have an autonomous robot, but also have a way to visualize the robot's movements and surroundings through my computer

Alright if you want to visualize, you will require sensor data such as LiDAR and IMUs to help localize a robot in virtual space. You can read more into getting started with the Navigation2 stack, or you can begin light with robot_localization. Nav2 has a detailed tutorial on getting started with it. If you need any help, feel free to start a new question :)
